# Would this cause a memory leak using linked lists?

Tags: c++, list, reference, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am programming a template for singly linked lists in C++ and I am  getting confused about what would be the right way of returning the information of the first node when deleting it.

I am getting some help from a book where there are written two methods, one that returns the value of the head node, and other that deletes it. Let's call that methods front() and pop(), where front() returns the value with a "const T&" type. One of my questions is, if I do something like this:

```
T object = list.front();
list.pop();
```

Wouldn't that result in an object reference pointing to nothing? Is there any problem if I continue using that object after calling pop()?

A second question is, what's the correct way of using the front() method and what's the difference between:

```
T object = list.front();
// or
T& object = list.front();
// or
const T& object = list.front();
```

Comment: `object` is an object, not a reference to an object. It's not pointing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do

```
T object = list.front();
```

and `front()` returns `T&`, then `object` becomes a *copy* of the initial element of the list, not a reference to it.

If, on the other hand, you write

```
const T& ref = list.front();
```

then the call to `list.pop()` would make `ref` a dangling reference, which is different from memory leak.

This should explain the difference between your first and third example; your second example, i.e.

```
T& object = list.front();
```

would not compile, because non-`const` reference cannot be constructed from a `const` reference.

Answer (score 2):

For `T object = list.front();`, `object` is a copy of `list.front()` and then has nothing to do with the original element. So `list.pop()` doesn't have any influence on it at all.

For `T& object = list.front();`, you can't do that. `const T&` can't be implicitly converted to `T&`.

For `const T& object = list.front();`, object is a reference to the element in `list`. So after `list.pop()` it will be dangled.